# Blazor, Bootstrap, table styling - how do I clean up the look of my table

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, blazor

How do I fix some of these styling issues of overlapping and sizing?

[image]

```
<table class="table table-striped table-sm table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date Worked</th>
            <th>Event Code</th>
            <th>Event Name</th>
            <th>Time In</th>
            <th>Time Out</th>
            <th>Hours Worked</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input @bind=newEntry.DateWorked /></td>
            <td>
                <select name="counties" id="counties" @onchange="@((args)=>Test(args, newEntry))">
                    <option value=" ">Select</option>
                    <option value="SWN">SWN</option>
                    <option value="WT">WT</option>
                    <option value="SE">SE</option>
                    <option value="HG">HG</option>
                    <option value="LM">LM</option>
                    <option value="WM">WM</option>
                    <option value="CLEAN">CLEAN</option>
                </select>
            </td>

            <td>@newEntry.EventName</td>
            <td><input @bind=newEntry.TimeIn /></td>
            <td><input @bind=newEntry.TimeOut /></td>
            @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newEntry.TimeIn) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newEntry.TimeOut))
            {
                <td>@(GetTimeElapsed(newEntry.TimeIn, newEntry.TimeOut))</td>
            }
            <td>
                <button @onclick="SaveNewRecord" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are already using Bootstrap classes for `table` and `button` elements so why not also use the appropriate Bootstrap classes for `input` and `select` elements?

Add [`form-control`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/forms/form-control/) class to your `input` elements and [`form-select`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/forms/select/) class to your `select` elements to have consistent and uniform styling.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the bootstrap framework in your application, then what @[Dimitris Maragkos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10839134/dimitris-maragkos) have mentioned, you can add the same in your application.

Use `form-control` and `form-select` to get a general appearance and sizing.
Refer to the below screenshot.

[image]

If you do not wish to use bootstrap styling, you need to manually add height to your select control by adding a custom style to your .css file.

Locate either *site.css* or any other *.css* file in the `wwwroot` folder. Adding the below style will apply height to all select control.

```
select {
  height: 28px; //adjust to your preference.
}
```

If you want to add the style to the select control inside table control only, use the below custom style.

```
table tr td select {
  height: 28px; //adjust to your preference.
}
```

[image]

**P.S.** Blazor 5.0 and onwards introduces [CSS isolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-6.0). Here, you can scope CSS to a particular component only. Create a *.razor.css* file matching the name of the *.razor* file for the component in the same folder, then add the custom style mentioned above.